# Fastest way to pass/notify data between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, httprequest, threadpool

I'm coding the following architecture
[image]

Currently the request is being made each 0.5 secs however the receiver is getting the update 3 seconds later. In this case even milliseconds matters. So the question is which should be the fastest way to share the data coming from the httprequest in order to the receiver can process it as soon the update was made it.

Comment: "The FASTEST way" is to use lock-free queues specifically for your threading pattern - Single Producer-Single Consumer, Multiple Producer-Single Consumer, etc. Google Disruptor, JCTools, Real-Logic Agrona... But this is about hundreds nano- and micro-seconds. Another important thing is that you should write GC/allocation-free code (no new objects/memory allocated in the main/hot path of the application).If you use Spring, Tomcat, some RDBMS and other regular java application stuff,you just waste your time finding "the fastest way", a standard BlockingQueue should be perfect for you

Answer (score 1):

One choise is `ArrayblockingQueue`.

Also you can use `ApplicationEventPublisher`
Thread1 publish an ApplicationEvent,
and Thread2 add `@EventListener` to this event.

Comment: ApplicationEventPublisher give me a new approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use an ArrayblockingQueue